# what is the recommended way to get a camera picture - getPicture or capture.captureImage

Tags: android, cordova

what is the recommended way to get a camera picture - `getPicture` or `capture.captureImage`? I can't figure out the difference, is there? what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if there's a particular preferred way, but personally i prefer the captureimage method - you can use the same method signatures for image, audio and video..